# Hyperparameter tuning using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am working on a dataset for which I am using linear regression to fit a model. Before signing off, I want to try using hyperparameter tuning to get the best model available.

I have been running the data through a pipeline to first convert string to number, then encode it, then vectorize all columns, then scale it before applying linear regression. I would love to know how do I set up the *grid* to start the hyperparameter ball rolling (so to speak).

```
import pyspark.ml.feature as ft
WD_indexer = ft.StringIndexer(inputCol="Wind_Direction", outputCol="WD-num")
WD_encoder = ft.OneHotEncoder(inputCol="WD-num", outputCol='WD-vec')
featuresCreator = ft.VectorAssembler(inputCols=["Dew_Point", "Temperature",
                                            "Pressure", "WD-vec", "Wind_Speed","Hours_Snow","Hours_Rain"], outputCol='features')

from pyspark.ml.feature import StandardScaler
feature_scaler = StandardScaler(inputCol="features",outputCol="sfeatures")

from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression(featuresCol="sfeatures",labelCol="PM_Reading")
```

So the pipeline looks like this:

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline( stages = [WD_indexer, WD_encoder, featuresCreator, feature_scaler, lr] )
```

How do I set up the grid for this pipeline?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I know this question was posted two years ago but still it does not hurt to keep everyone posted about latest findings and an alternative solution to your problem. As Frank Kane has explained in great details [here](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/big-datas-biggest-secret-hyperparameter-tuning), `CrossValidator` is pretty expensive since it is required to evaluate every possible combination of the specified hyperparameter values. As a result, it is suggested that you use `TrainValidationSplit` which evaluates only a single random train/test data split per combination. This could be very useful where you are dealing with very big datasets. Sample code from spark documentation (find more details [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-tuning.html#train-validation-split)):

```
# We use a ParamGridBuilder to construct a grid of parameters to search over.
# TrainValidationSplit will try all combinations of values and determine best model using
# the evaluator.
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder()\
    .addGrid(lr.regParam, [0.1, 0.01]) \
    .addGrid(lr.fitIntercept, [False, True])\
    .addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, [0.0, 0.5, 1.0])\
    .build()

# In this case the estimator is simply the linear regression.
# A TrainValidationSplit requires an Estimator, a set of Estimator ParamMaps, and an Evaluator.
tvs = TrainValidationSplit(estimator=lr,
                           estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                           evaluator=RegressionEvaluator(),
                           # 80% of the data will be used for training, 20% for validation.
                           trainRatio=0.8)

# Run TrainValidationSplit, and choose the best set of parameters.
model = tvs.fit(train)
```

Comment: when running the pramGrid for my lr model getting this error: 'PipelineModel' object has no attribute 'fitIntercept'. Any idea what the problem can be?

Comment: @SylwiaKmiec it's hard to answer your question without seeing a sample code but I assume this should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61257344/attributeerror-pipelinemodel-object-has-no-attribute-fitmultiple 
You are probably passing pipeline model to the param grid instead of a pipeline object.

Comment: Thanks, I actually solved the issue (don't remember what was the problem) but Thanks a lot for the link !

Answer (score 3):

You can setup a grid as using param grid builder & test using cross validation, from pyspark ml.tuning class.

```
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder
```

Then can decide the different parameters and their values you want to run:
You need to add a grid for each parameters & the array of values for each respectively
Eg, for linear regression you can pass values for, lr.regParam,lr.maxIter,lr.elasticNetParam

```
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(lr.maxIter, [10, 100, 1000]).addGrid(lr.regParam, [0.1, 0.01]).build()
```

You can also change parameters for vector assembler, string indexer & one hot encoding from the pipeline with featuresCreator.inputCols etc

```
crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline,
                      estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                      evaluator=RegressionEvaluator(),
                      numFolds=2)  # use 3+ folds in practice
```

You can run a training data trough cross validator to get the best model,

```
cvModel = crossval.fit(training)
```

Comment: Many thanks. I'll try that out. How can I do the set the parameters for layers in the grid if I am using neural networks?